# Logger service using logging package in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

There is a mention in the docs of using the logging package to create a proper logger service. Given the features in the logging package it would be nice to be able to get the angular component tree as the logger full name.

I tried to play a bit with the dependency injection system to get the injector tree, so that I could reconstruct the app structure for the loggers. But this proved to be too tricky.

Is there a way to do this, or alternatively, is there a canonical logger service that I could use? It seems to be a pretty basic feature so it must be available somewhere.

Comment: Could you point to "the docs" that mention this?

Comment: Sure, here:
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the [logging package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/logging) for help here.

This is not Angular-specific, but it supports tested loggers.